# How can I get php result and use it in bash?

Tags: bash, php

I have a php file that outputs 0 or 1.
How can I use this in bash as a condition ?

Comment: By "output", do you mean `echo` or `exit`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
result=$( php script.php )
if [ "$result" = "0" ] ; then
    # do stuff
else 
    # do other stuff
fi
```

Not sure on how PHP is called (parameters etc.)

Comment: If you don't want to create a bash script, just use like this: if [ "$( php script.php )" = "0" ] ; then echo "zero" ; else echo "one" ; fi

Answer (score 1):

That should work provided your php script writes to stdout and output only 0 on the first line.

```
exec 6<&0 #Saves stdin file descriptor to #6 fd.
exec < `php <your_script>`

read a

if 
    [ $a -eq 0 ]
then
    What you want to do
else 
    The other solution
fi

exec 0<&6 6<&- #Restores stdin and clear fd #6
```

Comment: Criticism corner: **1)** There is no need to save/restore stdin; you can `read` from any file descriptor (`read -u 7` or `read <&7`). **2)** Hardcoding a fd is unreliable. Better use `exec {fd}<foo`, this will set `$fd` to the allocated fd. **3)** The second line will expand either to `exec < 0` or `exec < 1`, which would try to read from a file named `0`. What _would_ work is `exec < <(php ...)` (process substitution). **4)** Now that you have `<( )`, you can avoid calling `exec` many times and simply use `read a < <(...)` or `read a <<< "$(...)"`. **5)** This can be reduced to `a=$(...)`.